# How to get timezone from address value with Google API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, google-api, geocoding

I am trying to use the Google API time zones, and first you must geocode the address to get the lat/long for time zone. 
How would I go about doing this from a value in a textarea? 2 steps,

1. convert textarea value to geocode example

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY

2. then use this lat/long to get the timezone example

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&key=API_KEY?

```
<textarea id="phyaddr">
123 Address
Suite 1200
Houston TX 77008     
USA
County:Harris
</textarea>
```

Comment: is that a question? It looks like you just described how to do it... if your looking for someone here to code it for you , they won't .  write the code yourself , then paste it here with specific parts you're having problems with

Comment: I need to know how to get the textarea value to url form with plus and commas, then grab the lat/long from the geocode output.

Comment: added a new answer , I think you are confused over the different API's that Google offers

Comment: You are correct in the calls you have to make.  But you should read the documentation for [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and [The Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/).  Also, search around a bit.  There are plenty of questions about each of these.  If you get stuck, show the code you tried when asking.  So far, all you've done is made a request for someone to write code for you - which is not what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

The Google WebService API is meant for server side GeoCoding ,  that url you have is to be sent from the sever, that is why it contains a key, you would not put that key anywhere in the client facing code.

there is another API called [Google Maps Javascript API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) , this is the one you use to make requests client side .  There are [Geocode Examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)  on the site of to do that :

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

see the first line `getElementById()` that is where you would put the ID of your element , which was your original question .

**You do realize that this is all for getting the Timezone of an address that the user entered? right, you can probably make them choose a Timezone while they are entering an address.**

if you simply just want the user's local timezone , well then that is much much easier , just this:

```
// this is offset from UTC time
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: I realize this. I'm handling data that already exists. How can I get the timeZoneName from Google TimeZone API output?

Comment: It looks like you use the address that the user entered , get the lat & long and send it to the server , from there hit that end point that you have in the post using the WebServices.  You got it , just make sure you make the call to the TimeZone service from your server

Comment: Regarding the last bit - that only returns the *current* time zone offset, which might change due to daylight saving time.  The Google Time Zone API returns a full time zone identifier, such as `America/Los_Angeles`.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).